# Is it possible to play sound effects with Android Auto using app types other than media-apps?

Tags: android, android-auto, android-automotive

Is it possible to play sound effects with Android Auto using app types other than media-apps (Messaging apps, Navigation, parking & charging apps)?

When I try to play a sound effect using "SoundPool API", it is muted and there is no sound while Android Auto is running.

Is there any good way?

My Source code
https://github.com/LeoAndo/android-auto-automotive-training/blob/main/SoundPoolAutoApp/app/src/main/java/com/leoleo/helloautoapp/sound/MainSoundPlayer.kt
https://github.com/LeoAndo/android-auto-automotive-training/blob/main/SoundPoolAutoApp/app/src/main/java/com/leoleo/helloautoapp/auto/MainScreen.kt

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

There has been progress.
With the implementation of voice-guidance, it was successful to run the app on the DHU and output sound from the smartphone speaker.(app type: POI)

references:
https://developer.android.com/training/cars/apps/navigation#voice-guidance
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media-apps/audio-focus

Comment: Your answer should have some sample code/commands.

Answer (score 0):

Was self resolved. By installing the implementation of audio focus, we were able to make sound on the car side.(App Type: POI)

[Reference](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media-apps/audio-focus)

Comment: please @LeoLeo you need to be more clear in how you present the problem, with the code reference rather than links. and the same with your answers. Notice you can edit your question, answers and comments. Usually users add Update in bold then add the info below in the question/answer. Thanks